# Can I stain bleached bamboo back to natural color?

Tags: stain

I picked up some outdoor bamboo shelving that's faded pale.  I'd like to stain it a creamy-yellow "natural" color and bring it inside.

After multiple attempts and vigorous sanding, I cannot get my test section to accept any stain.  Is there a trick to staining bamboo?

Comment: The main trick is sanding vigourously. Are you attached to the color of the stain?  Another option is using a blowtorch to caramelize it.

Comment: A little attached to the color, since I've already got other bamboo furniture in this color in the same room.  Sanding it is!